# Vue Cli Webpack Proxy

Tags: proxy, npm, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I've been developing with the vue-cli and the Webpack template. Everything works flawlessly but I'm having some issues using a custom host. Right now Webpack listens to localhost:8080 (or similar) and I want to be able to use a custom domain such as http://project.dev. Has anybody figured this out?

This might be where the problem resides: 
https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware

I also added this to the proxyTable:
`proxyTable: { 'localhost:8080' : 'http://host.dev'  }` and it gives me a console response `[HPM] Proxy Created / -> http://host.dev`

Any advice, direction or suggestion would be great!

*Update*

I successfully added a proxy to my Webppack project this way:

```
var mProxy = proxyMiddleware('/', {
   target: 'http://something.dev',
   changeOrigin: true,
   logLevel: 'debug'
}) 
app.use(mProxy)
```

This seems to work, but still not on port 80.

Console Log:
`[HPM] Proxy created: /  ->  http://something.dev`

I can assume the proxy is working! But my assets are not loaded when I access the url.

Is important to note I'm used to working with Mamp -- and its using port 80. So the only way I can run this proxy is to shut down Mamp and set the port to 80. It seems to work, but when I reload page with the proxy URL -- there is a little delay, trying to resolve, and then console outputs this:

```
[HPM] GET / -> http://mmm-vue-ktest.dev
[HPM] PROXY ERROR: ECONNRESET. something.dev -> http://something.dev/
```

And this displays in the browser:
`Error occured while trying to proxy to: mmm-vue-ktest.dev/`

Answer (score 0):

The proxy table is for forwarding requests to another server, like a development API server.

If you want the webpack dev server to run on this address, you have to add it to your OS's `hosts` file. Vue or we pack can't do this, it's the job of your OS.

Google will have simple guides for every OS.

Comment: Thanks! I have my address added to the etc/hosts on my OSx -- `127.0.0.1` points to `http://something.com` and I work with top level domains in php context all the time with no issues! But I can't seem to be able to do this with node

Comment: what exactly is "not working"? If you have `127.0.0.1 something.com` in your hosts file, entering `something.com:8080` will take you to the webpack dev server. If you want to change the port to the default `80`, do so in `/config.index.js`

Comment: I updated the question to avoid wiring more than in needed in the comments. That should give a more clearer idea of my issues